# How to click a link and open it in a new tab Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having trouble figuring out how to open a  link in a new tab using selenium Webdriver. I am getting stale exceptions in the loops because the pages are not correct after the first iteration. So my idea is to open the link in a new tab, do all the operations I want to do on that tab, and switch back to the old tab to continue the loop, but I am not too sure how to open these tabs and manage them.

```
        string year = this.yearTextBox2.Text;
        string semester = this.semesterTextBox2.Text;
        int numCourses = (int)this.numEnrollments.Value;
        int count = 0;

        string URL = GetURL(year, semester, "index");

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);

        //var result = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"uu-skip-target\"]/div[2]/div"));
        var results = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-light.btn-block"));

        // Loop through each department
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            // Make sure not to include the letter link
            // Click on this department and get the list of all courses

            r.Click();
            var result2 = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("class-details"));
            var results2 = result2.FindElements(By.XPath("./*[@class=\"class-info card mt-3\"]"));

            var courseCount = 0;

            // Loop through each course in the department
            foreach (var r2 in results2)
            {
                // Stop the process once reached the amount of courses needed to be scraped
                if (count >= numCourses)
                    break;

                Course c = new Course();
                c.year = year;
                c.semester = semester;

                var header = r2.FindElement(By.TagName("h3"));

                if (header != null)
                {
                    // Gets the course (CS 2420)
                    string courseNum = header.Text.Split('-')[0].Trim().ToUpper();
                    string[] depAndNum = courseNum.Split(' ');

                    // Separate department and number
                    c.department = depAndNum[0];
                    c.number = depAndNum[1];

                    // Get the course title
                    string text = header.Text.Split('-')[1].Trim();
                    c.title = text.Substring(4);

                    // Check if the course is a lecuture/seminar, if not then continue.
                    var list = result2.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".row.breadcrumb-list.list-unstyled"));
                    if (CourseIsLecture(list.FindElements(By.TagName("li"))))
                    {
                        c.count = courseCount;
                        GetCourseInformation(r2, c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        courseCount++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // Increment the course count on this department page
                courseCount++;
                // Increment total course count
                count++;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a click while holding the control key to force open the link in a new tab. You can use actions API for the same.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);

action.KeyDown(Keys.LeftControl).Click(r).KeyUp(Keys.LeftControl).Build().Perform();
```

However, I believe you might still get a stale reference exception when you come back to tab 0 and continue looping over results collection.If this happens to be the case, you can retrieve the count first and convert your foreach loop to a while/for loop and lookup your results collection every time inside while/for loop and then use results[i] to process that element further.
Another option could be to wrap your loop in a retry block e.g. using Polly framework and lookup results collection again in case of stale reference and retry the entire thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I may have to open 3 tabs, is this possible? And if so would switching tabs be indexed based from creation? Like the original tab is 0, first new tab is 1, and then the next new tab is 2, and so on.